# Munin throwing errors with fresh install

Tags: ubuntu, munin, graph

I just installed munin on a fresh ubuntu system, munin node throwing the following errors:

```
2013/01/30-21:10:02 CONNECT TCP Peer: "[::ffff:127.0.0.1]:39316" Local: "[::ffff:127.0.0.1]:4949"
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at /usr/share/perl5/Net/Server.pm line 600.

2013/01/30 21:15:06 [PERL WARNING] Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/munin/munin-graph line 74.
2013/01/30 21:15:06 [PERL WARNING] Use of uninitialized value $graph_fh in <HANDLE> at /usr/share/munin/munin-graph line 75.
2013/01/30 21:15:06 [PERL WARNING] readline() on unopened filehandle at /usr/share/munin/munin-graph line 75.
```

Do you have idea whats the problem? Here are the configuration files:

http://pastebin.com/sU8dVY1N - plugin-conf.d/munin-node

http://pastebin.com/NRHXn8it - munin-node.conf

pastebin.com/HMdiBfTh - munin.conf

Thank you very much!

Comment: could you post the contents around server.pm line 600 and munin-graph line 74?

Comment: I didn't modified these files, all are original.

http://pastebin.com/tkrP4YQr

Comment: This is a wild guess, but "Use of uninitialized value in pattern match" indicates to me that you miss something, maybe related to configuration. Is `host_name` set in `munin-node.conf`?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding this warning `Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at /usr/share/perl5/Net/Server.pm line 600.` take a look here: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=693320. Seems it is fixed in version 2.007-1 of libnet-server-perl package.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the domain you have set in `host_name` in `munin-node.conf` resolves.

If `localhost.localdomain` does not resolve on your system, try to change it to `localhost` or add an entry to `/etc/hosts`.